# Entity framework SQL server convert database to compact edition best practice

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, webforms

I have a question about SQL server and .net.

I started a project using asp.net 4 webforms and created a database using Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition (64-bit) and everything was working fine. I used entity framework and database first method.

My web hosting provider has only sql server 2008 (www.arvixe.com). I tried to create the DB on their servers and tried many different ways to upload the DB but seems it is not that easy.

Questions are,
1) can I use some SQL compact edition or other version and have a stand alone version of sql server ? 
2) if I am to user the compact edition, can I access the DB using sql server management studio ( database will be stored on a folder on the server_
3) what is the best and quick way to change the database (if required) ? 
4) is there any migration options available ? 
4) do i need to create the model again ? ( I tried but seems giving errors )

I just have two tables so it is not a big deal to create it but I don't want unnecessary complexities.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: One more question, is sql server compact edition works independently like MS Access ? is it s simple DB that only required .net framework on the server ?

Comment: is this issue resolved for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I just went through this and resolved it with the help of the [SQL Server Compact Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/). Once I sucked it up that I had to use a third-party tool I found the rock to roll smoothly. Here is a great deal of very practical and helpful information however once you download the [3.0.0.7 version](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/103781) you'll see that all you need to do is script your database schema and data then run that script on the SQLCE database from within the [SQL Server Compact Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/). When you go back into Visual Studio you'll see that the (tables only (no stored procedures/triggers/etc.) SQL Compact Edition database updated appropriately.

2) No. You can't connect to a SQLCE database from within SSMS. At least, after investing hours of research into ...I could not. Please correct me (forum) if I'm wrong in this.